# Can a WCF Ria Services entity be edited while submitting?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, ria

I have a silverlight application that uses WCF RIA services.

I want to submit changes every time a property is changed.

However if a user tries to change a another property in the same entity before the submit is complete I get the following error:

*"This entity is currently read-only. One of the following conditions exist: a custom method has been invoked, a submit operation is in progress, or edit operations are not supported for the entity Type"*

**Scenario:**

1. User changes property A in Entity 1
2. Application catches change and submits WCF DataContext
3. Soon after user changes property B in Entity 1. However this property is read-only due to submit in progress.

Is it possible change the behaviour of the DataContext so that I can update an entity during the submit process?

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE NOTE - I MIGHT BE WAYYYY OFF ON THIS RESPONSE:

Let me try to get what your saying:
   If i'm correct, on the interface, values are being changed which are bound to some entity.  This entity, is what you want to be updated in real time on the server.  If this is the case, I would recommend this:
   Let's say I have a text box, and as the user types the value in the text box, it updates the binding entity, and i want that entity to be updated on the server at the same time - define a behaviour to take the keyup method and trigger e.g. (`AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();`)
Also, in this behaviour, I would give the text box the ability to define a method to bind to for the OnKeyUp event allowing me, to say, once the user presses "Enter" then actually do the udpate on the server.  In addition, i would create a loading screen/child window to say "saving" - that would then cause "blocking" to occur to prevent any further user intervention during the save.  On the call back. I would close the window that said loading.

Now, like i said, i'm not sure if this is the answer your are looking for, but the theory behind the idea, especially the blocking only on enter or on a final change seems to be your best bet.  An example of the behaviour for the text box is below:

Include your library: `using CustomControlsUI.Extensions;`
Define the class for the text box: `public class TTextBoxKeyUpBehavior:Behavior<TextBox>`
Define the method pointer for the ontextkeyup that you want to dynamically bind to: `protected MethodInfo OnTextBoxKeyUp { get; set; }`
Define the public string that names the OnTextKeyUpMethod to bind to: `OnTextBoxKeyUpMethod`

Define the TextboxKeyUp event in the behavior:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method impl. for the onkey up event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void TextBoxKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!object.ReferenceEquals(AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty), null))
        {

            AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OnTextBoxKeyUpMethod) && !object.ReferenceEquals(AssociatedObject,null) && 
            !object.ReferenceEquals(AssociatedObject.DataContext,null))
        {
            try
            {
                //use reflection to try and find the method being pointed to.
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(OnTextBoxKeyUp, null))
                {
                    MethodInfo _m = null;
                    _m = AssociatedObject.DataContext.GetType().GetMethod(OnTextBoxKeyUpMethod, new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(KeyEventArgs) });
                    if (!object.ReferenceEquals(_m, null))
                        //set the pointer to the on text box key up method
                        OnTextBoxKeyUp = _m;
                }
                OnTextBoxKeyUp.Invoke(AssociatedObject.DataContext, new object[] { sender, e });
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        }
    }
```

Override the On Attached and On Detached methods:

```
protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.KeyUp += TextBoxKeyUp;
    }
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.KeyUp -= TextBoxKeyUp;
    }
```

Usage:
  Include the namespace where the behavior is stored: `xmlns:ccui="clr-namespace:CustomControlsUI.Behaviors;assembly=CustomControlsUI"`

Include the namespaces for System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
       xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Attach the OnKeyUpTo the desired method in the viewmodel:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,4,0,0" 
                                          Name="txtFirstName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <ccui:TTextBoxKeyUpBehavior OnTextBoxKeyUpMethod="OnSearchKeyUp" />
                                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                </TextBox>
```

Implement the method and property in the view model that should implement INotifyPropertyChanged found in System.ComponentModel

```
public string FirstName 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return __fFirstName; 
        }
        set
        {
            __fFirstName = value;
            //this is a custom extension on INotifyPropertyChanged
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName", PropertyChanged);
        }
    }
```

Finally define the key up method to notify the server of the change:

```
#region "Helper Method"
    public void OnSearchKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter && IsSearchStateValid==true)
        {
            OnFindCustomers(sender);
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Please Note: I could be WAYYYYYYYYYYY Off on this answer.  But it's just based on what i think you're looking for....